# FOSUserBundle & EventListener

Tags: symfony, service, fosuserbundle, event-listener

I trying to redirect user after register confirmation to homepage, but its does not work. Here is my listener:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * Listener responsible to change the redirection at the end of the password resetting
 */
class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegistrationConfirm'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('_welcome');

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

And the another question about relations, i have two entities, User and Profile, the related like OneToOne, i need to save both entities, i can reach this just use the cascade option={persist}, but user_id column in profile entity equal to NULL. Here is relations declaration:
User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $profile;
```

Profile entity:

```
 /**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profile")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

Service:

```
<service id="acme_user.registration_complete" class="Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener">
        <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
        <argument type="service" id="router" />
    </service>
```

Comment: could you past service definition?

Comment: sure. i added it to post

Comment: where is onRegistrationConfirm defined?

Comment: i just need to use REGISTRATION_SUCCESS instead of REGISTRATION_CONFIRM. tanks!